# Dropping various string variables in a loop in Stata

Tags: string, loops, stata

I want to a `drop` a great number of string variables that contain the word "Other" in their observations. As such, I tried the following loop to `drop` all the variables:

```
foreach var of varlist v1-v240 { 

drop `var' if  `var'=="Other"

}
```

What I get in return is the answer "syntax error". I would like to know not only a way to perform the task of dropping all the variables that contain the word "Other", but also why the code that I've entered returns an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If they are actual strings, this should work:

```
sysuse auto, clear

ds, has(type string) // get a list of string variables

// loop over each string variable, count observations that contain Buick anywhere, and drop the variable if N>0
foreach var of varlist `r(varlist)' {
    count if regexm(`var',"Buick") 
    if r(N)>0 {
        drop `var'
    }
}
```

If "contains" means *only* contains, then you need to use "^Buick$" instead or

```
count if `var'=="Buick"
```

Beware of leading/trailing spaces.

The if qualifier restricts the scope of a command to those observations for which the value of the expression is true. Your code errors because you are asking Stata to drop a variable (a column) if some observations (rows) satisfy a condition. You could use the if *qualifier* to drop those observations or you can drop a variable, but not both simultaneously. My code uses the if *command* (a different beast) to verify the condition, and then drops the variable if that condition is satisfied.

You might be tempted to do something like

```
if `var'=="Other" {
 drop `var'
}
```

but that will usually not work as expected (it would drop the variable only if the first observation was "Other").

Answer (score 4):

The short answer on why your syntax is illegal, which @Dimitriy Masterov doesn't quite spell out, is that `drop` supports just two syntaxes, which can't be mixed, `drop`ping variables and `drop`ping observations. This is documented: see e.g. http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?drop and the corresponding on-line help and manual entry within Stata.

In addition to other solutions, `findname` from the *Stata Journal* would allow this solution:

```
findname, any(@ == "Other") 
drop `r(varlist)'
```

Your interpretation of **contain** is evidently 'is equal to' judging by your use of `==` as an operator, echoed above. If **contain** really means 'includes as substring', then you need a syntax such as

```
any(strpos(@, "Other"))
```

or

```
any(regexm(@, "Other"))
```

as @Dimitriy also explains.

Comment: I must confess that I always forget what `findname` is called and can never seem to find it on my own.

Comment: I don't know how to help on that. It's in a strong sense a revision of `ds` (to which I contributed), but it is still user-written, so I had to give it a different name. The name `ds` originally meant something like "short describe", but it's mostly now a command for finding which variables satisfy specified conditions, and `findname` goes further on that. I didn't like `findvars` and `find` was already taken. If and only if you remembered its author, then `njc_stuff` (SSC) would serve as a reminder.